# sort error at end of proc sql for inner join

Tags: sas

I ran the following code and an hour later, just as the code was finishing a sort execute error occurred. Is there something wrong with my code or is my computer processor and Ram insufficient

```
proc sql;

create table today as

select a.account_number, a.client_type, a.device ,a.entry_date_est,

    a.entry_time_est, a.duration_seconds, a.channel_name, b.esn, b.service_start_date,

    b.service_end_date, b.product_name, b.billing_frequency_fee, b.plan_category,

    b.plan_subtype, b.plan_type

    from listen_nomiss a  inner join service_nomiss b

    on (a.account_number = b.account_number)

    order by account_number;

quit;
```

Comment: Can you post the precise error message?

Comment: It's possible that you are reaching the limit of your memsize setting. you can edit these settings, but If the sort errors persist after the MEMSIZE and SORTSIZE values have been significantly increased, it is likely that the errors are due to a lack of disk space.  Check to be sure you have plenty of space on the disk where your sas temporary folder is.

Comment: its going to take an hour before the error message occurs. i tried without the order by statement, so hopefully this works

Comment: just got this error     ERROR: Write to WORK.TODAY.DATA failed. File is full and may be damaged.

Answer (score 3):

That error is most commonly seen when you run out of utility space to perform the sort.  A few suggestions for troubleshooting are available in [this SAS KB post](http://support.sas.com/kb/39/705.html); the most useful suggestions:

- `options fullstimer msglevel=i ;` will give you a lot more information about what's going on behind the scenes, so you can troubleshoot what is causing the issue
- `proc options option=utilloc; run;` will tell you where the utility directory is that your temporary files will be created in for the sort.  Verify that about 3 times the space needed for the final table is available - sorting requires roughly 3 times the space in order to properly sort the dataset due to how the sort is processed.
- `OPTIONS COMPRESS;` will save some (possibly a lot of) space if not already enabled.

`options memsize;` and `options sortsize;` will tell you how much memory is allocated to SAS, and at what size a sort is done in memory versus on disk.  `sortsize` should be about 1/3 of `memsize` (given the requirement of 3x space to process it).  If your final table is around but just over `sortsize`, you may be better off trying to increase `sortsize` if the default is too low (same for memsize).

You could also have some issues with permissions; some of the other suggestions in the kb article relate to verifying you actually have permission to write to the utility directory, or that it exists at all.

Comment: could I omit the order by statement and then sort the data after the inner join is complete

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how that would take less space (although if it does, why not).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a project in the past where resources was an issue as well.
A couple of ways around it when sorting were:

- Don't forget that proc sort has a TAGSORT option, which will make it first only sort on the by statement variables and attach everything else afterwards. Useful when having many columns not involved in the by statement.
- Indexes: if you build an index of exactly the variables in your by-statement, you can use a by statement without sorting, it will rely on the index.
- Split it up: you can split up the dataset in multiple chunks and sort each chunk separately. Then you do a data step where you put them all in the set statement. When you use a by statement there as well, SAS will weave the records so that the result is also according to the by-statement.

Note that these approaches have a performance hit (maybe the third one only to a lesser extent) and indexes can give you headaches if you don't take them into account later on (or destroy them intentionally).

One note if/when you would rewrite the whole join as a SAS merge: keep in mind that SAS merge does not by itself mimic many-to-many joins. (it does one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-one) Probably not the case here (it rarely is), but i mention it to be on the safe side.